# Sharepoint Webpart called DatePicker swith to another day at 09:00 instead of 00:00

Tags: sharepoint-online, datepicker

I am working on SharePoint Online. I have created a page with a `DatePicker` on it and a list. I have configured the `DatePicker` that when a user
changes the date on the `DatePicker` the list updates. The day in the `DatePicker` is the current day and switches to another day but not at 00:00 but at 09:00.
How can I fix this? How to make the `DatePicker` switch day after at 00:00 instead of 09:00?

Greetings, Peter Kiers

Answer (score 0):

Most of these kinds of issues are Time Zone related.

Is your location 9 hours off of GMT? Have you set the default Time Zone for the Site Collection, or for your own account?

Comment: I am from The Netherlands. And time zone is set to (Utc+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Rome, Stockholm etc...

Comment: And set to Site Collection and my own account

Comment: Perhaps can this be done, by a code?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of time zone settings in SharePoint: Regional and Personal.

Regional setting controls time zone for the site – this the default time zone that every user will inherit. This setting is controlled by the Administrator.

Personal setting is something each user has control over and the control to override Administrative default setting.

Make sure you choose the correct time zone in both Regional setting and Personal Time Zone.

For more detailed information, refer to the following article:

https://sharepointmaven.com/sharepoint-time-zone/